# Jump to declaration does not work properly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I use Eclipse PDT with Aptana. When I started working, I could reliably use ctrl-click (or F3) on method names or functions to directly jump to the declaration.

Today, suddenly this does not work any more for all methods, it just works for some. I could not find out for which it works, yet.

I have already refreshed the project (F5 in PHP explorer window) and started eclipse with the "-clean" option, but neither helped. Hyperlinking is actived in the settings.

**EDIT:** I am using Helios Service Release 1, Build id: 20100917-0705

What can I try to make it work again?

Comment: Have you checked if your build path as suffered any changes?

Comment: No, nothing has changed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it looks like it was a user fault. My fault ... I had too many projects opened at the same time. Now, when I have only one project open, the hyperlinking works quite well again. I will watch further, but I am quite hopeful that I can now enjoy the full functionality of eclipse again.

Answer (score 4):

Did you update Eclipse?

"Remove files under workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2

Kepler repository has newer version of h2 database. It is incompatible to older one.
See eclipse/plugins folder, there might be org.h2_1.1.117.v201105142352.jar and org.h2_1.3.168.v201212121212.jar. (don't touch them)"

Comment: This solved my issue (updating from Helios to Kepler). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What did the job for me was this:
http://fsse8info.wordpress.com/2013/10/14/howto-get-eclipse-pdt-open-declaration-f3-working-again-with-php-files/

Answer (score 0):

Closing unrelated projects worked for me too, I was actually facing 2 issues.
Both intelligence ( ctrl+space) and open declaration  were not working. After clicking (right click->close unrelated project), Problem solved for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

If all above solutions don't work and still facing issues with some directories. Then you need to make sure `.buildpath` doesn't miss any directory and have all entries like:

```
buildpathentry kind="src" path="dir/dir1"
buildpathentry kind="src" path="dir/dir2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file has errors from classes missing a library reference. Right click project, Java build path, add library to fix reference issues, then the ctrl+click will work again